# He'd come throw rocks at me

Tags: grammar

Can you expain to me why author is using "he'd come throw rocks at me" instead of "he'd come to throw rocks at me" or "he'd come throwing rocks at me". It looks like gramatical error for me. The text is:

> I was afraid Jessie wouldn't come out and I'd be waiting here until dark. Or worse, that she'd tell Boo and **he'd come throw rocks at me**. But a few minutes after I'd climbed the tree, Jessie came bounding out of the house.

By the  way, there is the very simmilar gramatical text  which has correct gramatical form - "Jessie came bounding out of the house".

Comment: US casual/informal/regional dialect.

Answer (score 1):

(As Michael Harvey indicates in a comment)

This is an informal pattern mostly in American dialects.

It is standard English to use a to-infinitive with come (and other verbs of motion) do give the reason.  "He will come to fix my TV."  You can also express nearly the same with two coordinated clauses: "He will come and fix my TV"

It is possible to drop the "to" or "and":  "He'll come fix my TV". It is more common in speech, or (as in your example) in narration (we imagine there is a child speaking the story to us)

(I'm not certain, but I feel this pattern is unlikely in the past tense: *"He came fix my TV")